# in java,is there any easiest way to do tail -f functionality except common.apache.io.Tailer API

Tags: java

Using java, I want to monitor the log file and if any line from the log file match with given input string, it should print the log message. Also when starting this application, it should read from end of the log file, ie., it should read only updated log messages like `tail -f` not from the start of the log file. How do I implement this in java except using Apache common Tailer API?

Comment: You will get better responses if you explain exactly *why* you don't want to use Apache Tailer. If it's because of the work needed to set up, you're probably out of luck. Simply emulating `tail -f` functionality is easy: you block on StdIn. But you probably want to have this happening concurrently with other operations in your program, which means using a thread and probably a `FileChannel`. All of which are at least as complex as using Tailer, and don't have the benefit of a large(ish) user community.

Comment: please refer the following link. http://www.apacheserver.net/q154517/java-apache-common-tailer-api-reading-old-log-messages

Answer (score 0):

Create a [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to open the file, seek to the end and start using readLine(). The first line you get might be cropped by the left. You can seek back a bit before reading lines if you want to get some of the last lines. Then use a [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or whatever you want to test every line so when it matches 'the input string' you can print it.

When you reach EndOfFile readLine() will throw an EOFException so before reading a line you might want to take note of the current position ( getFilePointer() ) so you can seek there again and retry after you notice the file modification date or the file size changes. I think there is no need to close and reopen the file. To get modification date you need a [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html). File length can be obtained from RAF itself or from File.

I'm not sure about the need to seek back after EOFException for the case the file ends in the middle of a line (with no \n at the end).

You can use a FileChannel as suggested by @kdgregory if you want asynchronous behavior but it's not as straightforward as doing it synchronous and threads are cheap.